# In Vulgate Lk 22: 62, "Et egressus foras Petrus flevit amare.", it says. How to understand "flevit amare"?

Tags: vulgata, greek-to-latin-translation

I know "flevit" means "wept" and "amare" means "to love", but the Greek text is "ἔκλαυσεν πικρῶς", which means "wept bitterly".

If I parse the Latin text literally, it'll be "wept to love". What is the relation between "to love" and "bitterly" and why it was translated like this?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for making your first question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Amāre** indeed means to love, being the infinitive of the verb *amo*. Here, however, the word being used is **amārē** which is an adverb that is derived from the adjective *amarus* which means bitter. L&S [mentions](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=amarus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (II.C) 3 adverbs from *amarus* that mean bitterly. *amare* is one of them.

As far as I can see there is no etymological relation between *amarus* and *amo*.